# I have a Single column data. I want to reshape it so i can use this into RNN

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, deeplearning4j

I tried to reshape this but I'm getting error.
I have to use RNN before that I have to reshape it. Any idea?

```
X_train=np.reshape(Y,(Y.shape[0],Y.shape[1],1))
```

> IndexError: tuple index out of range [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMNs1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataset is most likely 1D, not 2D. Your code works for 2D just fine:

```
import numpy as np

Y = np.random.rand(3, 4)
print(Y)

Y = np.reshape(Y, (Y.shape[0], Y.shape[1], 1))
print(Y)
```

yields

```
[[0.94716449 0.46469876 0.74290887 0.11051443]
 [0.31187829 0.26831897 0.37580931 0.23038081]
 [0.46578756 0.81175453 0.98348175 0.02975313]]
```

```
[[[0.94716449]
  [0.46469876]
  [0.74290887]
  [0.11051443]]

 [[0.31187829]
  [0.26831897]
  [0.37580931]
  [0.23038081]]

 [[0.46578756]
  [0.81175453]
  [0.98348175]
  [0.02975313]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `reshape()` method can be called on a `numpy.array` directly, ie.:

```
Y = np.random.rand(3, 4)
Y.reshape((Y.shape[0], Y.shape[1], 1))
```

Output:

```
array([[[0.03398233],
        [0.31845358],
        [0.26508794],
        [0.4154345 ]],

       [[0.80924495],
        [0.86116906],
        [0.24186532],
        [0.64169452]],

       [[0.61352962],
        [0.95214732],
        [0.26994666],
        [0.99091755]]])
```

If your `Y` array is 1D you can still make it 3D like this:

```
Y.reshape((1, 1, -1))
```

Output:

```
array([[[0.52130672]],
       [[0.25807463]],
       [[0.81201524]],
       [[0.08846268]],
       [[0.20831986]],
       [[0.823997  ]],
       [[0.483052  ]],
       [[0.15120415]],
       [[0.19601734]],
       [[0.55933897]],
       [[0.9112403 ]],
       [[0.1048653 ]]])
```